# F# for the VM in a MVVM WPF environment?

Tags: mvvm, f#

Obviously F# would rule the model part, but would the choice be as clear for the VM part ?

Would the tooling support lost (any?) be compensated by the gain in the flexibility in the langage in a large application ?

Comment: That at least partly depends on what you're planning on doing in your VM.  If it's a pretty minimal VM, I can't see F# really helping you out with property declarations and such.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you don't rely on any major features of some MVVM framework, I'd say mostly it's as much as the choice of F# over C#, if that's the case of comparison.

The current F# compiler misses one feature that is useful in VM code though -- the support for `CallerMemberName` attribute, which is nice to use for `INPC` object properties. But this is probably a minor shortcoming compared to benefits you get (e.g. all the cool stuff in F#).

Since VM is often about transforming and processing the M data to use it in the V, I don't yet see why F# would be a bad fit.